# Scheduled Email Operations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a calendar widget with a some events scheduled and I want to send a specific email to multiple clients as per the schedule. Any hint to get started with this would be great.

Comment: Please provide more details..models, schema, what do you have so far?...at the moment your question is to general..

Comment: This question is too broad, primarily opinion based, and does not demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved, so doesn't fit as a question to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [delayed job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem to excecute "heavy" tasks on background.
And you can use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem to run tasks on certain moment.

Comment: Is there a way to handle this in a pub/sub model? i.e I want to publish a messages to an external system every second(looking into calendar) with a payload containing the information and I can use the external system to carry out the operation based on the payload.

Comment: With whenever gem you can execute some method in some model every day, or hour or whenever you want. On that method you can do whatever you want. I think that you have more than one question. You should split this issue on several questions...